# Why VScode changes the color scheme between identical files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I copied a script to a new file to change the name of the project. After doing this i noticed that the same variables and variable types had different colors.
Shouldn't the color scheme be the same for these files since it is the same code/language?

Copied file:
[image: [Copied file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q0IV.png)]

Original file:
[image: [Original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1i4E.png)]

I have tried the following:

- Changing between themes and coming back to the original (VScode dark modern).
- Disabling/enabling semantic highlighting.
- I tried copying the color scheme from the original but couldn't figure out how to paste it in the new file.
- I tried disabling and enabling the C/C++ and C/C++ Extension pack.
- I verified that Language Mode is the same.

Comment: Are file extensions the same for both? I think VSC uses file types to determine the language and parser/coloring to use.

Comment: @Alejandro Hello, yes. Same extensions.

Comment: Which language is it? Are the files in the same directory?

Comment: Check the file extension, sometimes VSCode uses different colors for different languages

Comment: Maybe verify the language mode used in those files. It is in the bar at the bottom of VSCode (near line and col number)

Comment: @kapex Hello, It's C and C++ since it's an arduino project. The copied files are in another directory.

Comment: @Mirco0 Hello, do you mean the c_cpp_properties.json file? I've checked that one and no difference and no color related configs either.

Comment: @Billuc Hello, I've checked and both are set to C++.

Comment: I recently used some extension for C which automatically added file extensions association in the code-workspace file, maybe you could check that

Comment: @kapex, I couldn't find that file. There are so many in the project folder and i don't know what i'm looking for

Comment: It's usually in the root folder of your project, the file extension is `.code-workspace`. But you'll only have it if you save the workspace as file. If you use "open folder" instead to load your project then you wont have it, which is fine.

Comment: It might not help directly, but you could use the action "Developer: Inspect editor token and scope" (hit ctrl+p and then write "inspect" into the search and you should see it). Then if you click on any text in the editor you can see what kind of token the highlighter thinks that text is. If there are differences, that would explain the different colors. I would guess that it might actually uses the same color scheme in both cases, but for some reason the tokens are interpreted differently.

Comment: @kapex Hello. Sorry for the delay in this response. I just tried using the Inspect tool and something weird happened. In the original file, I can see all the info that the tool displays but in the copied file it just says "Loading...". If i click in the output and inspect, all the information is there but when i click in the sketch, the tool just says "Loading..."